# how to add latitude and longitude coding in php ,as it shows map icon but if we click it takes to wrong URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I need a table with add,edit,delete and map button.In that everything works fine,but if click on map button,it should takes to google maps co-ordinates linked in a database  MySQL with latitude and longitude.But by below code if click it takes to google map ,but not taking latitude and longitude from databse. can you help me with that line ,as what i need to edit in that line.

```
<?php if(isset($result) && ($data_record) > 0)  : $i=1; ?>
                    <?php  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>

                        <tr class="<?=$users->id?>_del">
                            <td><?=$i;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->zonee;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->location;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->pop_type;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->switch_name;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_ip;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_make;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_serial;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_model;?></td>



                            <td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q='.$row['latitude'].','.$row['longitude'].'" target=\"_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>



                            <script>var page_<?php echo $users->id ?> = <?php echo json_encode($users);?></script>
                            <td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                            <a data="<?php echo  $users->id ?>" title="Delete <?php echo $users->name;?>" class="tip delete_check btn btn-info btn-sm "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php $i++; } ?>
            <?php else : echo '<tr><td colspan="8"><div align="center">-------No record found -----</div></td></tr>'; ?>
           <?php endif; ?>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
          <?php
              if(isset($_SESSION['flash_msg'])) :  
               $message = $_SESSION['flash_msg'];
               echo $error= '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <strong>'.$message.'</strong> </div>';
               unset($_SESSION['flash_msg']);
              endif;
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not echoing the latitute and longitute, and you are trying to use . operator outside php.

```
<td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?php echo $row['latitude'] . ',' . $row['longitude'];?>" target=\"_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>
```

Comment: <td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?=$users->latitude;?><?=$users->longitude;?>" target=\"_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>.

it takes only latitude ,it does not taking longitude.

Comment: still missing a comma in between latitude and longitude.

Comment: I had give,but it does not get longitude.

Comment: please comment your current code, then only we can check. Also it will be good if you can post php ouput of the same line.

Comment: <td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?=$users->latitude;?>,<?=$users->longitude;?>" target=\"_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>


o/p:
https://www.google.com/maps/search/12.2998528,/@12.9737535,77.6135156,15z/data=!3m1!4b1

Comment: I doubt you are missing longitude. To see php output you need to inspect the anchor tag ( or choose view source ) in your browser and make sure it is correct.

Comment: you are correct.in my database both latitude and longitude are stored in same column,i had found and changed it to separate columns.Thanks for your prompt reply.